# Weak form of linear ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Given the system $\frac{d\vec{y}}{dx}=\vec{Ay}+\vec{f}(x)$, $\vec{y}(0)=\vec{y}_0$, how does one transform this equation into the weak form? Unfortunately, I couldn't find much info on the internet in this respect.

Comment: ...Out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? As for how to do it, dot product both sides with a vector-valued test function. Then integrate by parts on the left side to move the derivative to the test function.

Comment: I got this question on the exam and I didn't quite know how to do it. What is a vector-valued test function?

Comment: It is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You should probably go to class...